# Submit forms with Command + Return

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

When editing a post (question/answer) I find it very handy that I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>.

However, on my Macbook, that's not that handy, because I'd expect to do <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Is it possible to add <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> on macOS?